# Magento 2 : How to put custom text in form validation?

Tags: magento2, requirejs, validation, ui

I have this message when i validate post code

[image]

How to change it?
I tried overriding postcode-validator.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'mageUtils',
'Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList'], function ($, utils, messageContainer) {
'use strict';

return {
    validatedPostCodeExample: [],

    /**
     * @param {*} postCode
     * @param {*} countryId
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    validate: function (postCode, countryId) {
        var patterns = window.checkoutConfig.postCodes[countryId],
            pattern, regex;

        this.validatedPostCodeExample = [];

        console.log("RADI" + postCode + countryId);

        $.get("/checker/PostalCode/CheckPostalCode", {data:postCode}, function (data) {
            console.log("Response text " + data.data);
        });

        return true;

    }
};});
```

But this display only this default message. I tried adding this in postcode input field but no luck:

```
$('input[name=postcode]').attr('data-msg-required','Please can you work!.');
```

Comment: What do you want actually? you want to override postcode-validator.js

Comment: @GPrathap Yes i want to override postcode-validator.js in a way that it can check postcode not by regex but with some api and display custom message in div I screenshoted in post. I just want to display any text in that div and span.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
First copy **postcode-validator.js** 
from

> vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/modal/postcode-validator.js

to

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/modal/postcode-validator.js

then Create require-config.js inside you module frontend folder and then add below code

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/modal/postcode-validator': 'Vendor_Module/js/modal/postcode-validator'
    }
},};
```

Then it will override the core postcode-validator.js

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But how i can change text in div when error occurs? Like this one from picture at start of my question. I want to put custom text in that div. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So basically you validation right?

Comment: Well, yes. I just want to check zip code and display my message when it is not good.

Comment: Which form is this? I mean shipping or your custom page form?

Comment: Yes, it is default form on checkout/#shipping

Comment: Try this,
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251843/magento-2checkout-phone-number-field-should-accept-numbers-plus-special-charact/255192#255192

Comment: Sorry man but i don't have reputation to comment on that post or to chat. I can't understand what exactly do you refer on that post by saying  Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rules.js Is that in my module folder or? i just want to change that message :( Thanks in advance good man!

Comment: You need to add custom validation in order to display custom message and custom allowed zip codes .

Comment: Yes, I added my postcode-validator but i can't show my message. I don't know how

Comment: Where did you added, just follow my steps or create chat link